# Teysa + Painter's servant replacement

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I am building a commander deck for my little brother with [Teysa, Orzhov Scion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teysa%2C%20Orzhov%20Scion) as commander and I noticed that Teysa + [Painter's Servant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Painter%27s%20Servant) is a nice combo, but Painter's servant is expensive and I believe not even legal in commander. I really liked this interaction though, so I was wondering if there is another card I could use as a replacement (that's not too expensive).

The combo in question being the following:

1. Have Painter's Servant replacement named black
2. Have 3 white creature (tokens) to sacrifice
3. Use Teysa's activated ability to exile a creature
4. Teysa's second ability triggers on each of the tokens dying, generating 3 new tokens
5. Repeat the process until you opponents have nothing left

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [mtg:] autocard feature does not work with apostrophes in card names, which is why I didn't link the correct name.

Comment: @Hackworth No problem

Comment: Painter's Servant is indeed banned in Commander, you can find the full banlist [here](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php).

Comment: Luckily in Duel Commander, it's legal :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, there is no such replacement for Painter's Servant.**

There are some permanent cards that change the colors of all creatures, such as [Shifting Sky](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shifting%20Sky) or [Darkest Hour](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darkest%20Hour), but none of them add colors to creatures, they all replace them with a single color.

With [Sleight of Mind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sleight%20of%20Mind) or [similar cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+%5B%22Change%20the%20text%20of%22%5D+%5Bcolor%5D%7C%7Ctext=+%5B%22Change%20the%20text%20of%22%5D+%5Bcolor%5D) you could replace all of occurences of "black" on Teysa with "white" or vice versa. That would allow that specific Teysa to do the combo with any 3 white (or black) creatures. However, with all such cards being blue, they would be outside of your commander's color identity and thus not legal for a Commander deck.

For future reference, under http://gatherer.wizards.com you will find the Oracle database, the official and searchable MtG card database.

Comment: I think that wouldn't even work since it says that they become the chosen color (not in addition to their other types) so I would have all black tokens which I couldn't sac to Teysa or all white tokens which would mean I wouldn't get any tokens from teysa's second ability

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't know what exact combo you were referring to though.

Comment: I have added the combo/synergy to my post now

Comment: Wouldn't Slight of Mind (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3945) work for this? Just replace all instances of "white" with "black" (or vice-versa).

Comment: @GendoIkari Good point, that would work. Unfortunately, only outside of Commander. And also a good point why these kinds of questions are really hard to answer comprehensively, because there seems to be always one more combo to make it work.

Comment: @Hackworth Oh right, looks like all such cards are blue and thus won't work with Teysa as commander.